# Write to dynamic partition Java-Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, hive

I've created the following table in Hive:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (..columns...) PARTITIONED BY (load_date string) STORED AS ...
```

And I'm trying to insert data to my table with spark as follow:

```
Dataset<Row> dfSelect = df.withColumn("load_date","15_07_2018");
dfSelect.write().mode("append").partitionBy("load_date").save(path);
```

And also make the following configuration:

```
sqlContext().setConf("hive.exec.dynamic.partition","true");
sqlContext().setConf("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode","nonstrict");
```

And after I make the write command I see on HDFS the directory `/myDbPath/load_date=15_07_2018`, which contains the file that I've written but when I make query like:

```
show partitions mytable
```

or

```
select * from mytable where load_date="15_07_2018"
```

I get 0 records.

What happened and how can I fix this?

#### EDIT

If I run the following command in Hue:

```
msck repair table mytable
```

I solve the problem, how can I do it in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive stores a list of partitions for each table in its metastore. If, however, new partitions are **directly added to HDFS** (say by using hadoop fs -put command (or) .save..etc), the metastore (and hence Hive) will not be aware of these partitions unless the user runs either of the below commands

1. Meta store check command (msck repair table)

> `msck repair table <db.name>.<table_name>;`

**(or)**

2. ALTER TABLE table_name ADD PARTITION commands on each of the newly added partitions.

We can also add partition by using alter table statement by using this way we need to add each and every newly created partition to the table

> ```
> alter table <db.name>.<table_name> add partition(load_date="15_07_2018") location <hdfs-location>;
> ```

Run either of the above statements and then check the data again for load_date="15_07_2018"

For more details refer these links [add partitions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL) and [msck repair table](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-RecoverPartitions(MSCKREPAIRTABLE))

Comment: Probably this link will give u some insights regarding adding partitions using java  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39807098/extract-hive-table-partition-in-spark-java/39807932#39807932

Comment: Thank you, Can I do it from SparkSQL?

Comment: Yes, Initialize and use hive context then execute the msck repair table **hiveContext.sql("msck repair table <db_name>.<table_name>")**
.. if you are using Spark 2.0+ then **spark.sql("msck repair table <db_name>.<table_name>")**

Comment: Ok, But I need to do it every time when I make save command? Its not should make performace problem?

Comment: if you are writing data to **HDFS location directly** then **every time** needs to execute **msck repair table stmt** to add newly created partitions to hive table and i don't think there is any performance issues.
another way of doing this is creating dynamic partitions in hive table using spark,refer to this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31341498/save-spark-dataframe-as-dynamic-partitioned-table-in-hive.. if we create partitions like this way you don't have to run msck repair table again.